# Is there a free online chess repertoire tool?

Tags: opening, software, repertoire

Is there a free online chess repertoire tool? It can be some place where you register, save variations and comments, and navigate with a board what you do. I was used to *chessply*, but apparently it disappeared.

Comment: https://lichess.org/study

Answer (score 12):

In addition to the other answers, there are a few sites to consider. These include annotation and comment features as mentioned by the OP.

[**Listudy.org**](https://listudy.org)
Upload a PGN and then you play the computer interactively. You play moves from your repertoire and the computer plays the opponent moves. This is also open source.

[**ChessTempo.com**](https://chesstempo.com/)
Similar functionality in the "Opening Trainer." The interface is a bit different but it tracks what lines you have learned a bit differently which is nice.

[**lichess.org**](https://lichess.org/study)
As [B.Swan](https://chess.stackexchange.com/users/15478/b-swan) has pointed out in a [comment](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/34896/is-there-a-free-online-chess-repertoire-tool#comment56845_34896), the Study feature includes this. Further, [Hauptideal](https://chess.stackexchange.com/users/27380/hauptideal) points out in a [comment](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/34896/is-there-a-free-online-chess-repertoire-tool/34913?noredirect=1#comment65041_34913) you can use the Analysis feature's book icon to access master statistics, lichess statistics, and statistics of any lichess account you want.

---

There are also other related sites worth exploring to understand their capabilities and how they may supplement the resources above.

[**ChessTree.com**](http://www.chesstree.net/)
Import/export PGNs. Search databases, get statistics. See opening relationships in a graphical tree.

[**OpeningTree.com**](https://www.openingtree.com/)
Import/export PGNs.  Import and analyze a user's openings from a database, PGN, etc, including popular online chess sites.

Comment: The opening tree functionality was added natively to lichess for own lichess games

Comment: @Hauptideal thanks, I'll look into it and update the answer accordingly once I've tested its functionality relative to the OP's question.  Appreciate the tip!

Comment: @Hauptideal do you have a link to what you're referring to?

Comment: https://lichess.org/analysis
Click on the book icon and select player. You'll get master statistics, lichess statistics and statistics of any lichess account you want.

Comment: @Hauptideal Ah. Thanks. I know about that.  I was hoping you meant something more.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 7):

There is already an offline program which has a lot of my ideas implemented:

http://www.chesspositiontrainer.com/index.php/en/features

But there is no good online tool which comes even close to that, let alone surpassing the linked offline tool. And I think an online tool, which stores the individual repertoire databases on a serve, would be much better, because then you could use the tool from any device, PC, tablet or smartphone. And if professionally made the online tool could easily surpass the offline tool linked above.

Answer (score 6):

I was looking for the exact same thing and could not find what I wanted so I ended up building this free tool [mychessnotebook.com](http://mychessnotebook.com) ! It is a text editor which will automatically replace FEN formulas with pictures representing the chessboard (upon PDF export).

[image: demo]

Answer (score 5):

https://www.chess.com/openings

This opening explorer is so incredibly comprehensive and intuitive that I cannot imagine anything better. Just make sure you use the website, not the mobile app. The app is trash. The website is better optimized for mobile than the mobile app.

Answer (score 4):

You may have a look at https://chess-repertoire-companion.com

It is free, online and still under development. You can use it from all your devices.

[image]

Comment: I think this is a great initiative!

The only problem I see is that it doesn't recognize transpositions. For example, 1. e4 d6 2. d4 Nf6 3. Nf3 is correctly identified as the Roscher gambit from the Pirc, but the moves 1. e4 d6 2. Nf3 Nf6 3. d4 which leads to the exact same position is not identified as such. 

Hope you will overcome this.

Answer (score 0):

maybe [openings101.org](https://openings101.org) is what you are looking for.