# Alternative to ChessBase Replay training feature

Tags: software, training, chessbase

I've used the ChessBase Replay training feature on my friends PC and now I am missing it. ChessBase is too costly for me. I've tried lichess.org: Practice with computer but instead of playing the moves in the PGN it starts playing its best moves which is quite good but annoying too. I need this feature to remember my own openings and sidelines.

My question: is there any open source or free software with this feature that can repeat the PGNs move and alert me when I make a non listed move (maybe suggesting it as blunder or good move)?

P.S.: I am currently using chess pad 2.0 with Stockfish. Can we add this feature to Chess pad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Listudy.org**](https://listudy.org)
Upload a PGN and then you play the computer interactively. You play moves from your repertoire and the computer plays the opponent moves. This is also open source.

[**ChessTempo.com**](https://chesstempo.com/)
Similar functionality in the "Opening Trainer." The interface is a bit different but it tracks what lines you have learned a bit differently which is nice.

See more at this [related answer](https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/34913/26335).

Comment: Mods, let me know if I need to make this a community wiki...not sure on this site's preferences for this situation.

Comment: Oh Man this is the thing I needed! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [chessable.com](https://chessable.com), it is possible to create your own course by importing pgns. The spaced repetition software will then test you on the variations in the pgn the same as the purchasable courses from other authors.

After signing in to the website open the drop down menu and select 'Create a Course' then follow the instructions.

I believe it isn't 100% free as there is a soft limit to the number of free courses you can own. But the functionality is good.

Answer (score 2):

SCID allows what you want. Look at "Play" menu and any of the submenus "Opening training" or "Tactics" or "Review game" or "Calculation of variations.